# Combine a Flow and a non Flow api response Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I currently have a piece of logic as follows:

```
interface anotherRepository {
      fun getThings():  Flow<List<String>>
}
```

```
interface repository {
    suspend fun getSomeThings(): AsyncResult<SomeThings>
}
```

```
when (val result = repository.getSomeThings()) {
            is AsyncResult.Success -> {
                anotherRepository.getThings().collectLatest {
                    // update the state
                }
                else -> { }
            }
        }
```

The problem I am having is that, if `repository.getSomeThings` has been triggered multiple times before, `anotherRepository.getThings` is getting triggered for the amount of all the pre-loaded values from `repository.getSomeThings`. I was wondering what is the proper way to use these repositories, one a suspend function, the other a Flow together. The equivalent behaviour that is combineLatest{} in Rx.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain a bit what you want to happen exactly? Do you want a flow based on `getThings()` which combines each value of `getThings()` with the current value of `getSomeThings()`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Joffrey, what I want to have is that, every time the `getThings` flow emits, I want to pair it with whatever last value was loaded with the suspend fun `getSomeThings()`  does this help?

Comment: What do you mean by the last value of `getSomeThings()`? This function does not emit new values, it returns a value whenever you ask it to do it. Do you want to execute this function repeatedly to acquire new values?

Comment: `getSomeThings()` emits when triggered of course. However what i am seeing is there the `collectLatest` lambda gets triggered multiple times everytime `getThings` emits. with different values from `getSomeThings()` (previous loaded values)

Comment: Essentially i need a combineLatest for the two different types. AsyncResult + Flow.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I assume `AsyncResult` isn't a flow/stream of values, but a single, already received value. So this is much different than `combineLatest()` which combines streams of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem. One way is just to call
`repository.getSomeThings()` in the `collectLatest` block and cache last result:

```
var lastResult: AsyncResult<SomeThings>? = null

anotherRepository.getThings().collectLatest {
    if (lastResult == null) {
        lastResult = repository.getSomeThings()
    }
    // use lastResult and List<String>
}
```

Another approach is to create a `Flow`, which will be calling `repository.getSomeThings()` function, and [`combine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) two Flows:

```
combine(
  anotherRepository.getThings(),
  flow {emit(repository.getSomeThings())}
) { result1: List<String>, result2: AsyncResult<SomeThings>  ->
  ...
}
```